# Unable to set the value of a variable to state variable in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am getting API response and once after getting that I am applying some filter and want to assign the result to state variables.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
filtered = this.state.result
      .filter(value => value.Date == bar.Date)
      .reduce((acc, e) => acc.concat(e.FailureDeatils), []);
    this.setState({ failureResultValue: filtered });<-- Here I am able to set the filtered to failureResultValue.
```

Again on this failureResultValue,I am applying filter and able to achieve the result i.e.

```
failureResultTransactions = this.state.failureResultValue
      .filter(data => data.name == pie.name)
      .reduce((acc, item) => acc.concat(item.TransactionDetails) , []).map(item => ({ ...item, checked: false }));
console.log(failureResultTransactions );<- It has value
this.setState({ items: failureResultTransactions });<- This is not working
console.log(this.state.items)<- is returning empty
```

Can anyone figure out where I am going wrong?

Comment: `setState` is [async](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), you cannot just console after the `setState` function

Comment: You can not do setState and expect the new state value in the next line. React documentation clearly mentions that setState will update the state whenever react finds it convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 this.setState({ items: failureResultTransactions },()=>
    console.log(this.state.items));
```

You can check like this